# Why is printf blocked by while(trylock) on CentOS 7?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, centos7

Start two threads with policy SCHED_RR and priority 45.
One thread's affinity is 0x0004, and another is 0x0008.(my computer contains four cpu cores. system is `CentOS 7`, not a virtual machine.)

The subTask is simple:

1. spinning trylock in the while.
2. call printf show the information.
3. free the lock.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define CHECK_ERROR(call)\
do{\
    int _error = (call);\
    if(_error != 0){\
        printf("*** Error *** at [%s:%d] error=%d \n", __FILE__, __LINE__, _error);\
    }\
}while(0)

int getThreadCores(pthread_t thread, int *cores);
int getThreadPP(pthread_t thread, int *policy, int *priority);
int setThreadAttrCores(pthread_attr_t *attr, int cores);
int setThreadAttrPP(pthread_attr_t *attr, int policy, int priority);

#define SUB_THREAD_NUM (2)
static int threadsId[SUB_THREAD_NUM];
static pthread_t subThreads[SUB_THREAD_NUM];
static pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *subTask(void *data)
{
    int id = *(int*)data;
    int policy=0, priority=0, cores=0;
    CHECK_ERROR(getThreadCores(pthread_self(), &cores));
    CHECK_ERROR(getThreadPP(pthread_self(), &policy, &priority));
    printf("the sub thread %d, cores 0x%x, policy %d, priority %d\n",
            id,cores,policy,priority);

    int n = 1024*10;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        while(pthread_mutex_trylock(&lock)){}
        printf("the sub thread %d, out put %d\n",id,i);
        CHECK_ERROR(pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock));
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    CHECK_ERROR(pthread_attr_init(&attr));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<SUB_THREAD_NUM;++i)
    {
        threadsId[i] = i;
        CHECK_ERROR(setThreadAttrCores(&attr, 0x0004<<i));
        CHECK_ERROR(setThreadAttrPP(&attr, SCHED_RR, 1));
        CHECK_ERROR(pthread_create(&subThreads[i],&attr,subTask,threadsId+i));
    }
    CHECK_ERROR(pthread_attr_destroy(&attr));

    for(i=0;i<SUB_THREAD_NUM;++i)
    {
        CHECK_ERROR(pthread_join(subThreads[i],NULL));
    }

    printf("multiThreadTest success\n");
    
    return 0;
}

int getThreadCores(pthread_t thread, int *cores)
{
    int error = 0;
    int cpuNum = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF);
    int _cores = 0;
    cpu_set_t mask;
    CPU_ZERO(&mask);
    error = pthread_getaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask);
    if(error == 0)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<cpuNum;++i)
        {
            if(CPU_ISSET(i, &mask))
            {
                _cores |= (0x1 << i);
            }
        }
    }
    *cores = _cores;
    return error;
}

int getThreadPP(pthread_t thread, int *policy, int *priority)
{
    int error = 0;
    struct sched_param sp;
    error = pthread_getschedparam(thread,policy,&sp);
    *priority = sp.sched_priority;
    return error;
}

static void setCpuSetMask(cpu_set_t *mask, int cores)
{
    int cpuNum = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF);
    CPU_ZERO(mask);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cpuNum;++i)
    {
        if(((cores>>i)&0x1) == 1)
        {
            CPU_SET(i, mask);
        }
    }
}

int setThreadAttrCores(pthread_attr_t *attr, int cores)
{
    cpu_set_t mask;
    if(cores<0)cores=0xFFFFFFFF;
    setCpuSetMask(&mask,cores);
    return pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(attr, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask);
}

int setThreadAttrPriority(pthread_attr_t *attr, int priority)
{
    struct sched_param sp;
    sp.sched_priority = priority;
    return pthread_attr_setschedparam(attr,&sp);
}

int setThreadAttrPP(pthread_attr_t *attr, int policy, int priority)
{
    int error = 0;
    //firstly, set the inherit to PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED
    error |= pthread_attr_setinheritsched(attr,PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    error |= pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(attr,policy);
    error |= setThreadAttrPriority(attr,priority);
    return error;
}
```

compile: gcc -Wall -O3 -lpthread multiThreadTest.c -o multiThreadTest

My question is: the program blocked, one thread blocked in `printf` and another blocked in spinning trylock, why?

[image]

If I change the policy to `SCHED_OTHER` and the priority to 0, the program unblocked.

If I change the `while(pthread_mutex_trylock(&lock)){}` to `CHECK_ERROR(pthread_mutex_lock(&lock));` the program unblocked.

If I change the `while(pthread_mutex_trylock(&lock)){}` to `while(pthread_mutex_trylock(&lock)){usleep(1);}` the program unblocked.

And if I change the `printf` to `fprintf`, the program unblocked.

And if I run the same program on `Ubuntu system`, it is unblocked.

Comment: When I was using `SCHED_RR` in a production/shipping product (circa 2008), and I could be be wrong about this, my research indicated that priorities higher than 11 could cause the program to block some internal kernel threads and destabilize/freeze the system.

Comment: my computer system is centos 7，even if I change the priority to 1，the program still blocked

Comment: The functions `getThreadCores`, `getThreadPP`, etc. are unknown. I can guess a bit, but my guess may not match your actual code. Please _edit_ your question and post them. You could edit your original code block to make it standalone and complete. That is, a single `.c` that has no `#include` except for the standard ones, and all functions that compiles cleanly. So, it can be downloaded, compiled, linked, and run. So, we need a `main` function as well.

Comment: What's the point of the spinning `pthread_mutex_trylock()`?  How is it not strictly worse than a single `pthread_mutex_lock()`?

Comment: I have improved the code and showed the compiler options

Comment: so I want to compare their performance in my application

Comment: I tried this program on a PC with 4 cores running Ubuntu dist and it works... Are you on a virtual machine?

Comment: my pc runs centos 7. it's not a virtual machine. I will try the program on Ubuntu

Comment: it's unblocked on Ubuntu, so amazing, but the system of my project is CentOS 7, I have to figure it out.

Comment: The snapshot shows lines 69 and 74 for the threads. According to the sources that you shared, those are respectively: empty line right before getThreadCore() and "int _cores = 0;" in function getThreadCores()". This does not match. Are you sharing the source code which fails?

Comment: I have changed the snapshot. It already corresponds to the code

Comment: How are you running the program? The image you present suggests that you're running it under control of some IDE (I don't recognize which).  If so, have you tried starting it directly from a shell?

Comment: the results are same, when I run it on the shell and the IDE(eclipse). I post the image which captured from eclipse, to show the details of blocking.

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with your code, and I am unable to reproduce your issue on my CentOS 8 Stream workstation.  Probably you have stumbled across a bug.  I speculate it may be related to combining the round-robin scheduler with assigning threads non-default CPU affinity.  It's unclear why you're using either one, and especially unclear why you're combining them.  You should experiment with your options on those fronts.  I don't know any reason in principle why those shouldn't combine, but giving up one or both may provide a suitable workaround.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug of CentOS7. I research performance (low latency and high  bandwidth) by chaning those options.